# Update multiple rows or record in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

If I have a script like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Status='0'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
       $id = $row['ID'];

           //.........

       if($process->send()) { //after sent
         mysql_query("UPDATE table 
                      SET Status ='1' 
                      WHERE ID = '$id'"); 
       }
    }
```

So it will update each row when process is done.But if I have more than ten thousand records with the `Status='0'`, the update will become slow .

So is there any better way to update the record? I can't update all with one single query since I need to know whether each process is done or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Updating one row on a decent indexed million rows table should be instant. How many updates are you sending to the server per second?

Comment: @Lieven It's not instant, it always takes a few milliseconds. If you try doing 1000s of them per second it **will** become slow, **especially** when using a lot of indexes, since they have to be recalculated on each update.

Comment: Shove the entire task into another thread. Parallise it. Shoev it into another thread, but just do the next one with a status of 0, usoing your table as queue.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - You took the *instant* too literaly but MySQL should be able to handle 1000 updates per second (not that it's a good idea). [These guys](http://johanandersson.blogspot.com/2010/10/mysql-cluster-performance-update-on-pk_11.html) get 120.000/sec (clustered).

Comment: @Lieven It's probably possible, but getting all updates into one query is definitely faster, since the indexes only have to be updated once, etc.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - I assumed it couldn't be done with one query as per OP's own words but your answer is a good alternative (upvoted already).

Comment: @Lieven Thanks for your reply.I will check my database to see if there is any problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add all successful ones to an array and simply commit all of those simultaneously.

```
if ($process->send()) {
    $done[] = $id;
}
```

and a bit later:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET Status=1 WHERE ID IN ('.implode(',', $done).')');
```

Comment: +1 as this is definitly a performance improvement but OP has other problems too if it's server isn't able to handle thousand updates/sec (or updating a table with a few thousand records, depending on how you interpretate the question).

Comment: To be noted that IN would perform badly if there is too much items. I think the OP has to try both solutions and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of MySQL you are using you might consider setting up a function that has the procedure stored that way you can offset this process to the Database so that it doesn't delay your script in running.

> Documentation for Create Procedure/Create Function:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 2):

If the UPDATE query is executing slow, you can use the LOW_PRIORITY keyword for MyISAM storage engine:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Example:

> `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY SET Status = 1 WHERE id = someid;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a stored procedure for that code. It works very fast

Comment: A stored procedure isn't going to be noticably faster for an update as simple as this.